# Do I need Singapore Transit Visa if I am travelling from India to Hong Kong?

Tags: india, transit-visas, hong-kong, singapore-airlines

I am an Indian national and traveling to Hong Kong from India. I have a transit at Singapore for 3 hours. I don't have to do the self-transfer. Do I need a transit visa for the same?

Answer (score 3):

The document database TIMATIC states

> > Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
> country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit
> area of the airport and have documents required for the next
> destination.